# How do you know that someone else is working in a file in the project in Visual Studio under Git in Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, version-control

This has to be a very simple question, but I can´t find an aswer.
I´m using Visual Studio Team Services in Visual Studio 2015, using the Git plugin.
When I (let´s say Programmer A) open a file for edit, I can see a red tick in Solution Explorer indicating that the file has been modified.
But how can a collegue (Programmer B), that is working from somewhere else, know that Programmer A is working on that file?
Also, when Programmer A finishes editing and commits and pushes the changes, a blue lock appears again on his Solution Explorer so he knows his local version is updated. But how can Programmer B know that his local version is not? The same blue lock appears on his Solution Explorer. He can of course Fetch to see if there pending changes, or Sync and then get them, but when does he know he should do that?

Wrapping it up: is there a way to know...?

First: That someone else is working in a file in the project.

Second: That some changes have been made your local copy doesn´t have.

I don´t know if I am overlooking something, but it seems to me that to have this information is very important working in a team.

PS - I use male pronouns for readability, no assumptions here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wrapping it up: is there a way to know...?

No, there is not a way to know.  That is the nature of distributed source control.

> ...it seems to me that to have this information is very important working in a team.

No, it is not very important information.  The tools are designed on the (in practice almost always correct) assumption that combining conflicting changes after the fact is less cumbersome than trying to know enough to avoid ever making conflicting changes.  (Some older tools did use "pessimistic locking" schemes; they are terrible to work with.  You can think that's my opinion, but if you look at the direction things have moved in the industry you'll see that it's not *just* my opinion.)

If a person is not in the habit of periodically fetching and seeing if new changes exist, they'll find out when they try to push (because the push will be rejected and they'll be instructed to pull and merge in the changes at that point).

> PS - I use male pronouns for readability, no assumptions here ;)

PS - in the 20th century I used male pronouns for readability; in the interim I have learned that language is for communication, and that communication is hindered by using forms that a significant number of people find offensive, whether I agree with their offense or not.  You will find that "they" as a singular pronoun is now recognized as acceptable, and to many people preferred, English.